# rsyslog.service is not working -> deprecated

Tags: linux

After restarting the rsyslog.service i've encountered the below error

● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-06-17 15:27:54 CEST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
           http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
 Main PID: 2050 (rsyslogd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
           └─2050 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n

Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...

Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging rsyslogd[2050]:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="2050" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging rsyslogd[2050]: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]

Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging rsyslogd[2050]: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]

Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Jun 17 15:27:54 lux-logging rsyslogd[2050]: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop'

## action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [v8.24.0 try

http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ] #

The solution is not so clear -> http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to check configuration file try:

```
rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslogd.conf -N 1
```

How do you restart the service?

`-N 1` is better verbosity level. 0 is default.

Comment: I used 
service rsyslog restart

Thank you for the above comment

Answer (score 0):

This setting has been deprecated in new Linux versions don't use this option in rsyslog.conf file to remove this warning you need to change rsyslog.conf settings which are placed in /etc/rsyslog.conf you need to find and remove **& ~**

```
$template RemoteLog,"/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* -?RemoteLog
& ~
```

after removing these options it should look like this.

```
$template RemoteLog,"/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* -?RemoteLog
```

then reboot rsyslog service and check the status this waring will not appear.

Comment: I am using rsyslogd  8.2102.0-15.el8 on rhel 8.9 and removing the &~ does stop the warnings but if I do my filter stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your statement:

> The solution is not so clear -> http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307

Follow that link and click on large-lettered title: "rsyslog error 2307".  The next page says,

> Examples in v7 are the discard action (~ indicator), which has been replaced by the (better) alternative “stop” statement

So replace the tilda character, **~**, with the word **stop**.